# MS SQL Table structure for dynamic app

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I am building a dynamic app.

The basic of the app is i can create a question. A question may have many columns. These columns will be displayed in table structure. Then the user will fill the details.  Below is the sample.

Question:
1. List the projects available and their deadlines?

Columns:
1. Project - Textbox
2. Deadline - Textbox

So i will show this data in the table like below.

[image]

The user will fill the row and click on submit button. Another empty row will get added to add the another response like below.

[image]

The user will submit any no of responses.

Like this the no of columns will be dynamic and also the each column will have some validation like Unique,AcceptsNull etc...

How to create table structure in ms sql server to save the question,column and the responses.

Please help thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the information you've given I'm thinking something like this?

```
Questions       
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | Question                                           |
+----+--------------------------------------------------- +
|  1 | "List the projects available and their deadlines?" |
+---------------------------------------------------------+

Answers
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | QuestionId | Order | Title      | Anwser      | Unique | Nullable | Values   |
+----+------------+-------+------------+-------------+--------+----------+----------+
|  1 |          1 |     0 | "Project"  | "Project 1" |   True |    False | "P1, P2" |
|  2 |          1 |     1 | "Deadline" | "Apr-15"    |  False |     True | NULL     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Edit: I've added the validations. If you want the same validations for all anwers for the same question, you can also move the validation columns to the Questions-table.

Comment: There are multiple responses available for question. How will you handle it?

Comment: By adding a new record in the awsers-table with the same `QuestionId`.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario is similar with the way in which `Microsoft Project Server` stores its data in `MSSQL`. In MSPE for each project, a task can have a dynamic number of columns. In your case, if you can make all your column types as `VARCHAR`, than your scenario simplifies even more.

The proposed structure would be like this:

This is the table with the questions:

tbl_Questions

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id          | Question                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------- +
| RandomGUID1 | "List the projects available and their deadlines?" |
| RandomGUID2 | "List the projects available?"                     |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

tbl_RelationTable

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id     | QuestionId  | Column1        | Column2       | ... |Column 1000  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      1 | RandomGUID1 | RandomGUID111  | RandomGUID112 |     | null        |
|      2 | RandomGUID2 | RandomGUID113  | null          |     | null        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In this table you store all relations between tbl_Questions and the other tables. You define in this table a sufficient number of columns, here I proposed 1000, but maybe in your case 10-15 columns would be enough. One important aspect is that you need to use GUIDs for Question ID in order to be unique.

Now we define the real data tables.
This is the table where you define your answer columns:

tbl_AnswerColumns

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|Id| RelationTableId | QuestionId  | ColumnName |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 1| RandomGUID111   | RandomGUID1 | Title      |
| 2| RandomGUID112   | RandomGUID1 | Answer     |
| 3| RandomGUID113   | RandomGUID2 | Title      |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

This is the table where you store the answers values:

tbl_AnswerValues

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|Id| RelationTableId | QuestionId  | Answer     |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 1| RandomGUID111   | RandomGUID1 | "Answer1"  |
| 2| RandomGUID112   | RandomGUID1 | "Answer2"  |
| 3| RandomGUID113   | RandomGUID2 | "Answer3"  |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

You need to define foreign keys in all tables in order to make the data retrieval  much faster. This is why each table should contain a foreign key to the QuestionId.

Comment: Each column will have specific attributes. Like Column 1 will be textbox whereas column2 will be dropdown. Where will you save this infos

Comment: You can add a new column to tbl_AnswerColumns: ColumnType, also for dropDown, you can add another column with PossibleValues.